# Exclude one of two same-name folders in Visual Studio Code Search

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my project, there are two folders `config` and `xxx/config`:

```
.
├── config
└── xxx/config
```

I want to exclude the `config` folder while keeping `xxx/config` folder when doing search in Visual Studio Code.

I tried:

```json
"search.exclude": {
    "config": true, // not working
    "**/config": true, // excluded wrong one
    "./config": true, // not working
    "${workspaceFolder}/config": true, // not working
    // ... ...
    }
```

Is there a (simple) way to do this?

EDIT:

Thanks for @Timothy G.'s great advice. It proves that a simple `config` will do the job.

However, this setting will not take effect immediately in my VSCode (Strangely enough, some other changes in `search.exclude` take effect immediately). I have to restart it to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't following standard JSON format - you are suppose to have a `:` followed by `true` or `false` for the various glob patterns (Visual Studio Code should be throwing an error at you too).

Try this:

```json
"search.exclude": {
   "*config": true
}
```

I tested this with a setup of a folder that contains two more folders called "Hello" and "Other".  The "Other" folder contains another "Hello" folder.  Both "Hello" folders contain a text file, where the first "Hello" folder in the Root folder is the one I want my search to exclude.  Both text files contain the text "Find me".

With the JSON property set to false, it finds the text "Find Me" in both files:

[image: both found]

With it set to true, it only finds the text in the Other/Hello folder:

[image: other/hello found]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Changing to the right JSON format and it seems to start working. However, as my indent is to **exclude Hello but keep Other\Hello**, simply writing “Hello”: true will not work (it excludes both). Any idea on how to write the name?

Comment: @Qiuye-Hua I read which folder you wanted to exclude wrong... After some more tests, I find that putting `"Hello": true` or `"*Hello": true`  achieves what you want.  Thus `"config": true` should work, but if not, try adding the asterisk.  If this still doesn't work, it might be because of where your current workspace folder is, as the global patterns are relative to that.

Comment: Or, now that you have the JSON correct, perhaps try `"${workspaceFolder}/config": true` again